# Add template tag inside another one in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I add a template tag inside another template tag? Below is an example what works, but it's not dynamically correct.

```
{% for keyword in lp.keywords.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'tag' 'mytag' %}">#{{ keyword }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**This is what I basically want:**

```
{% for keyword in lp.keywords.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'tag' '{{ keyword }}' %}">#{{ keyword }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is your question how to pass parameters to the url tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `keyword` is a parameter you want to give to the `url` tag then just do this

```
{% url 'tag' keyword %}
```

[url tag docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Answer (score 3):

Just pass it as a variable:

```
<a href="{% url 'tag' keyword %}">#{{ keyword }}</a>
```